# How can I remove issues with my flyway springboot project?

Tags: flyway

So while building a new database using our database migration scripts written in a springboot flyway project, we realized we made some mistakes.

Some old scripts need to be changed to ensure that we do not face these issues when we make a new database schema again. These issues are mostly related - an info table was not populated with entries in the project and there are scripts that refer to the data in the migration project -- this data does not exist because we never included a script to include data.

How can we correct this project - the only way I can think of is to correct scripts such that all inserts are replaced by - insert if not exists or replace create statements by create if not exists.

and then delete all entries in schema version and re-run this on all the database which are using this schema.

I cannot go back and correct my script because then the migration project will fail because of checksum issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rigth, if this project and the scripts are running in some existing projects you can not modify them because the checksum would fail.

Then the cleanest way I can think would be add a file called "DB-GENERAL-FIXES" or something like that, where you can add all SQL validations to restore the DB to a stable status. For the new implementations will be extra work first build it wrongly and then clean it, but if you are sharing the same code in production right now...is the best option

Comment: That makes sense but the project fails midway. Like if there 10 scripts, the project stops running at the 5th script because something in the script did not take into account that we might run it to create a fresh schema in a new db. So I have to make some db changes to ensure that the whole project can run fine and these db changes have to be done before the 5th script runs.

Comment: @Tisha Yes unfortunately you have to create some scripts even if you know the tables, rows or whatever will be removed in future scripts, but you have to do in the new projects all the DB evolution to use the same